# How to update StatefulWidget from other class?

Tags: flutter, widget, stateful

First of all, I'm a real beginner with Flutter, so I have probably not even grasped the basic design patterns yet. My problem is probably simple for someone who understands flutter. Here goes:

I have a tabbed GUI in my app and a floating action button. Each tab has a list that I want to update using that action button (FAB). The easy way to do this seemed to have one action button for each tab, but I read that you should not do this in flutter. So I made the button "global" and call a method on the current tab when the button is pressed. The method then adds some data that should be shown in the list, but the problem is that the list of course isn't actually updated just because I add data. The setState() is never called inside that list widget.

All the exampels I've found are very simple with the FAB being inside the list having access to its setState() method. But in my case I'm outside the list. How do I solve this? Notifier? Stream? I'm lost...

Comment: I tried with a stream from my data collection to the widget, it works, but no idea if this is the correct/pretty way to do it...

Comment: You can give that subclass a function for it to call when it's time. That function could do `setState` near the FAB. Or you could investigate `InheritedWidget`.

Comment: You can check my answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/55451162/2315974,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55396386/2315974, they explain your situation a bit :).

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct solution is to use a "Stack" and "Positioned" widged like:

```
- Stack
  - Scaffold
    - TabBar
  - Positioned
    - FloatingActionButton
```